# HTTP Post request with body returns null

Tags: swift, post, httprequest, nsurlrequest, swifty-json

I am using trying to post some data to server using Swift URLRequest with using following code.

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: Global.ip)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let postString = "cmd=getFavorites" + "&ab={\"userId\":\"\(userId)\",\"favId\":\"\(favoriteId)\",\"favoriData\":\(panelData)}&token=\(token)"
let newPostString = postString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
request.httpBody = newPostString?.data(using: .utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
{                                                   data, response, error in

    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        completion(false)
        return;
    }
    let json = JSON(data)
    completion(true)
}
task.resume()
```

My panel data consists of lots of json like following. It could be more than 10 panel data like below JSON.

```
{"userId":"sampleUser","favoriId":"123456","favoriPanelData":[{"filterData": {
  "type" : "0",
  "code" : "0",
  "year" : 2018,
  "value1" : "0",
  "value2" : false,
  "value3" : "0",
  "value4" : "2018\/06",
  "value5" : 2018
},"defName":"abc","config": {
  "left" : 0,
  "height" : "6",
  "resizable" : true,
  "titlebar" : true,
  "settings" : true,
  "draggable" : true,
  "width" : 5,
  "bottom" : 6,
  "right" : 5,
  "top" : 0
},"memberName":"genName1"}]}
```

However, it is not posting that url to the server and I do not understand why is it happening. When I asked our server-side they told me that url have a limit for posting most probably you are not sending POST request. When I research on the internet POST request in Swift like above. Where am I missing how do I need to send POST request so it is not struggling limit?

Comment: "you are not sending POST request", that's not the case since you implemented `request.httpMethod = "POST"`. Based on your current issue, I would assume that you are getting an error in the response (`error == nil` is `false`), could you mention the `error` if its not `nil`?

Comment: Error is nil so I am not getting any error so my error = nil is true. Is it possible that the body I am sending is too long? @AhmadF

Comment: Then you might want to convert the `data` to string and check its value...

Comment: When I convert data to string it is showing me login.html page which is my Global.ip address @AhmadF

Comment: Well, as a suggestion, you might want to test the API using a tool (postman for example) *before* even jumping to the code to make sure how to deal it first...

Comment: When we look logs request method is GET not POST but I specified as a POST? @AhmadF

Comment: Based on [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest/2011415-httpmethod) (unless its value is edited from somewhere in your code) it should be POST. That's why I suggested to test it on Postman :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176654/discussion-between-atalay-asa-and-ahmad-f).